# Adding coins inside a ring of coins

Tags: mathematics, geometry, optimization, packing

17 identical coins with diameter 1 are lying flat on a table, such that their midpoints build the vertices of a regular 17-gon (regular heptadecagon) and adjacent coins touch each other.

What is the maximum number of coins, which can be added inside the 17-gon, none of them overlap and lying flat on the table?

Note: the coins to add are of the same size as the coins building the 17-gon.

Comment: If it's the pool table I used to play on at a dive by the beach, then fifty easy. That thing was all kind of warped

Comment: Are you, by any chance, in the process of making pepperoni pizza? :-)

Answer (score 6):

I'll get things started with

> 14

> [image]

Comment: I got the same, filling concentric rings of width 1. It likely cannot be improved by 2 coins, assuming [this best-known 33-coin packing](http://hydra.nat.uni-magdeburg.de/packing/cci/cci33.html) is indeed optimal, but it is hard to tell whether maybe one extra coin can be squeezed in.

Comment: loopy walt pointed out a way to prove that it is optimal at the current state of research.

Answer (score 5):

UPDATE: @Rob Pratt's is optimal at current state of research:

> Here is the best known packing of 32 circles into a regular heptadekagon.
>  
>  [image]
>  
>  Coordinates taken from http://hydra.nat.uni-magdeburg.de/packing/ced/ced.html
>  If we could pack 15 circles into a regular 17-ring we would beat that. Therefore if we believe the experts it is not possible.

> Mind you, it's pretty darn close. All the red lines indicate touches. Those which are not marked but look as if they ought to be are less than 6 permille (1/10), 3 permille (1/10) or less than 1 permille (8/10) of a radius apart.

original post:

Tada!

> 15:
>  [image]

No, sorry, I actually cheated.

> There is a tiny amount of overlap between 30,31 30,24 and 31,25.

Comment: Interesting. This (your cheating solution) is on 17-coins ring, and it's so close to a solution, yet by adding one more coin in the circumference it still can't fit? (because otherwise we would have 33-coin config for 18-gon)

Comment: @justhalf I don't understand. One can actually relatively easily fit 16 inside an 18-ring.

Comment: Oh, I misread your answer. I thought the line of thought was "with N-gon, we can fit M coins inside, totaling N+M coins. If we can fit M+1 in N-1-gon, we can simply add one coin to the outer ring to get M+1 coins inside N-gon, totaling N+M+1, beating the optimal, which is "impossible"". So why is Rob's answer with 14 coins inside 17-gon not able to be improved to 15 coins inside? The total is still 32, which is the optimal one.

Comment: @justhalf the subtlety is that fitting 15 in a 17-ring is harder than fitting 32 in a circle that can just hold the 17-ring because placing 17 as a ring is not optimal for the task of putting 32 no matter how. In fact, 32 can be packed in a circle that is actually too small to hold a 17-ring, so we do not get a bound from that. The 17-gon is in between easier than the ring but harder than the circle. And it happens to yield a bound for the ring question.

Comment: Ah, ok. That's the part I'm missing. Thanks for the explanation! It's a bit complex then to say that we can't fit 15 into 17-gon. Maybe you can elaborate more on the image caption?